# Is there a way to turn gvim into fullscreen mode?

Tags: gnome, vim

Is there a way to turn gvim into fullscreen mode? I know that this is possible on OS X through MacVim, but wasn't able to find a way to do it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With gnome you can set a shortucut to the "fullscreen" action. Use gnome-keybinding-properties, select Window Managaer and choose Change to Fullscreen, then select a shorcut (F11 for example). This shortcut will set the current Gnome Window in fullscreen mode.

This doesn't work unless the *Enable Extra WM Actions* plugin is checked in the *Compiz Settings Manager*

Comment: Thank you, that did it for me. Just for folks who don't know how to do this the exact steps I followed are: 
  - Click on `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`
  - Go to the `Window Management` category
  - Select `Toggle full screen mode` and apply the `F11` shortcut

Comment: I've bound F11 to be the full screen key but when I press it in gVim, the window just flashes and nothing happens. It works in other apps. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

The system settings do not work for me on Ubuntu 12.04 (as happens to miloshadzic) because gvim catches the F11 key and does not pass it on to the system.

There is a solution though, that [I found in this blog](http://www.windowslinuxosx.com/q/answers-how-can-i-open-gvim-in-full-screen-mode-in-gnome-264693.html)

make sure you have `wmctrl` installed. If you have that, then add the following to your vimrc:

```
map <silent> <F11>
\    :call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,fullscreen")<CR>
```

And on save of the .vimrc and restart of gvim F11 now has the desired effect.

Answer (score 4):

For XFCE Users:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> works out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch into fullscreen mode by changing the lines and columns settings. Try to put this into your vimrc:

```
if has('gui_running')
    set lines=999 columns=999
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

## Maximised window instead of fullscreen

**If you have a right-side XFCE launcher panel,** the `fullscreen` option of `wmctrl` causes `gvim` to overlap.

Below variant with `maximized_vert,maximized_horz` resolves this issue and enables <kbd>F11</kbd> for maximised window toggling:

```
command! Maximised :call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz")
noremap  <silent> <F11> :Maximised<CR>
vnoremap <silent> <F11> <C-C>:Maximised<CR>
inoremap <silent> <F11> <C-O>:Maximised<CR>
```

---

## Automated, upon starting `gvim`

Place the following line in `gvimrc`, for a foolproof fullscreen at `gvim` startup:

```
autocmd GUIEnter * call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz")
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu cinnamon go to `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `Windows` -> `Toggle fullscreen state`. Set as `F11` for example.